# Change grub menu text

Tags: boot, kali-linux, grub2

I am using Kali Linux and I changed my grub background image by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file, after that I updated the grub. But now when I boot the PC the line to boot Kali says 'Ubuntu' instead of 'Kali Linux'. The text for the Windows 10 partition stays normal with 'Windows 10'. Does anyone know how I can change the text on the grub menu?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `menuentry` definitions in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`; that is where the text of the menu entry is defined.  However, it's quite likely that when the GRUB package is updated, the configuration is regenerated from the shards located in `/etc/grub.d/`; consult the `README` file therein for details on how to edit these to taste.